# Possible error with this combinations problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can 5 cards be chosen one after the other from a $52$-card deck without replacement?

According to the answer, it is $52!/47!$ which does not make sense to me.

My answer is $C(52,5) = 52!/(47!5!)$. The reason is we do not care about order and is without replacement. So we use combinations.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the important phrase is *chosen one after the other.....without replacement*. So order matters.

Comment: The question might be a little vague. Does it want a sequence or a set of 5 cards? The words “one after the other” suggests a sequence. Suppose the question asked “5 cards chosen to form a (poker) hand”, then it would be a set. To be honest, the question could do with more clarity.

Comment: @AnuragA I think the keyword is “one after the other”, whereas “without replacement” is just a standard phrase, preventing you from interpreting it to be a multi-set or a sequence with repeatable elements.